# Confluence CSS Widget Not Formatting Text

Tags: html, css, confluence

I am trying to improve the styling of my Confluence page, but when I insert a `{css}` widget the styling does not take effect for many different elements and formatting styles.

For example:

```
{css}
  body {
    font-size: 24px;
  }

  p {
    color: red;
  }

  div.atest {
    color: blue;
  }
{css}
```

In this case, all my font is 72px. But no simple paragraph blocks are red, nor are any div's (given the `atest` class) showing as blue.

Is there some special formatting in Confluence that must be done for CSS to be handled properly, or does it only support a small subset?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that your CSS is correct but it is not considered, add !important to the styling to prevent it being overwritten by inner elements like so:

```
p {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must tag a {HTML} {HTML} first.
I'm still working with an older Version..

Else i have found this

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Styling+Confluence+with+CSS

Hope this helps